# Remote access Windows from Mac OSX?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have Googled and I found some remote access tools.

From Microsoft: [Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads)

From Apple: [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/)

Which one should I use?

What's the difference between these two:

1. Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac 2.1.0 >
2. Remote Desktop Connection Client 1.0.3 for Mac >

Comment: Microsoft's Remote Desktop is for remote desktop to Windows. Apple Remote Desktop is for remote desktop (and a lot more besides) to macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remotely administrated a bunch of from my Mac Laptop recently. I had two tools that I would use hourly, if not daily:

1) Microsoft's remote desktop for Mac works almost flawlessly for connecting to windows servers/desktops.

2) I have a Windows 7 VM installed on my machine (with VMWare Fusion, but there are other options out there as well). Being able to open a cmd.exe on my mac was pretty killer. I am a heavy pstools user, so not needing to remotely connect was nice for some tasks.

As far as I know the Apple remote desktop is a tool for administrating remote mac desktops.

Answer (score 1):

I always enjoyed CoRD for OS X. You can keep profiles, which is handy, and it's free.

http://cord.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have not seen CoRD before. I'll have to give it a shot next time I dabble in the windows world. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Mac client I prefer to use is [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/), especially as I need to connect to multiple servers. Unlike the Microsoft RDP client, CoRD actually works properly. The Command key translates to the Windows key on the remote machine and the clipboard functions correctly.